# Trying to login to Xbox/Microsoft with Selenium, but Log In button never gets pressed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Edit 2**:
Based on the accepted answer, I made modifications that were necessary for the code to work. I added `expected_conditions` because Selenium still couldn't find the element until I did this. Here is the final code replacement for the answer.

```
log_in = (By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@value, "Sign in")]')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(log_in)).click()
```

and here is the replacement for my entire login code. You will see that I changed my password field to wait until clickable, and not present. This is because now, the password wasn't getting entered until I did this.

```
    def login(user, passwd):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        # chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        driver = Chrome("C:\\bin\\chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(login_url)

        un_field = (By.ID, "i0116")
        pw_field = (By.ID, "i0118")
        next_button = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(un_field)).send_keys(user)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(next_button)).click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(pw_field)).send_keys(passwd)

        log_in = (By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@value, "Sign in")]')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(log_in)).click()


        return driver
```

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I am using Selenium Webdriver with Chrome to try to login to Microsoft / Xbox Live. I am using explicit waits to wait until an element is present or can be clicked. The problem is, after successfully entering the username, clicking "Next", and entering the password, my program never clicks "Log In", and just continues execution.

```
    def login(user, passwd):
        chrome_options = Options()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        driver = Chrome("C:\\bin\\chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(login_url)

        un_field = (By.ID, "i0116")
        pw_field = (By.ID, "i0118")
        next_button = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(un_field)).send_keys(user)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(next_button)).click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(pw_field)).send_keys(passwd)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(next_button)).click()

        return driver
```

I suspect the cause of this issue is the fact that the "Next" button from the previous screen, and the "Log In" button from the password screen have the same element ID, yet I don't get any errors, which puzzles me. I have even tried pressing Return with `Keys.RETURN` in the password field instead of clicking "Log In" with `.click()`, but that doesn't work.
Also, when running without headless mode, it almost looks like the next page that I get with my driver later in the code interrupts the login screen, but I can't be sure.

**Edit**: The page being used is [here](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&rver=7.3.6963.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Faccount.xbox.com%2Fen-us%2Faccountcreation%3FreturnUrl%3Dhttps:%252f%252fwww.xbox.com:443%252fen-US%252flive%26ru%3Dhttps:%252f%252fwww.xbox.com%252fen-US%252flive%26rtc%3D1&lc=1033&id=292543&aadredir=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is caused by the same ID, declare a separate variable for the Log In button using text:

```
log_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Log In")]')

log_in.click()
```

**EDIT:**

I've looked at the login form on xbox live, the URL you've provided. The button you want to click after entering your password is Sign in, and that is its VALUE, not TEXT.

Try this xpath:

```
log_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@value, "Sign in")]')

log_in.click()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not very familiar with Xpath. I'll look into it myself, but I also added the link to the login page in an edit to my original question. It still doesn't work, even after modifying the text to match the value for the element. (That being "Log in", not "Log In")

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a modification by using a tuple with `By` so I can use `expected_conditions` so I can detect when the element is present. I'll put the modification in an edit to my original post.

Comment: Glad I could help. :) And you were right to change it from 'present' to 'clickable'. I usually use 'element visible', but the end result is the same. 'present' does not always means 'visible' to Selenium, and so sometimes clicking fails.